# XSLT grouping with filter

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do XSLT grouping within a call template while applying a filter. The below code works fine but it is not considering the filter condition and is returning all the nodes . Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong . My understanding is that is that it has something to do with the scope of the below line

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('ParentName',@ParentName)" >
```

Here is the xml and xslt .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Documentation>
  <Consequences>
    <Nodes>
      <Node1 name ="abc1"  ParentName="Group1" IsInternal ="true" />
      <Node1 name ="abc2" ParentName="Group2" IsInternal ="true"/>
      <Node1 name ="bcd1"  ParentName="Group2" IsInternal ="true" />
      <Node1 name ="bcd2" ParentName="Group1" IsInternal ="false"/>
      <Node1 name ="efg1"  ParentName="Group2" IsInternal ="false"/>
      <Node1 name ="efg2" ParentName="Group1" IsInternal ="false" />
    </Nodes>
  </Consequences>
    </Documentation>
```

XSLT : -

```
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="Consequences" >        
                      <xsl:call-template name="Template1">
                         <xsl:with-param name="NodeList" select="Nodes/Node1[@IsInternal='true']"/>    
                      </xsl:call-template>

      </xsl:template>

        <xsl:key name="ParentName" match="Node1" use="@ParentName" />

       <xsl:template  name ="Template1">  
         <xsl:param name="NodeList" />


          <xsl:for-each select="$NodeList[generate-id()=generate-id(key('ParentName',@ParentName)[1])]">
            <Group>
              <xsl:value-of select="@ParentName" />

             <xsl:for-each select="key('ParentName',@ParentName)" >
               <SubItems>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
               </SubItems>
             </xsl:for-each>
           </Group>
          </xsl:for-each>  

      </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to select only the elements who's `@IsInternal='true'`, instead of simply all of the `Node1` elements that have the specified `@ParenName`.

Your `xsl:key` is matching on all of the `Node1` elements and indexed by the `@ParentName` value. If you are only using that key to retrieve the elements who's `@IsInternal='true'`, then you can add a predicate filter to the match criteria:

```
<xsl:key name="ParentName" match="Node1[@IsInternal='true']" use="@ParentName" />
```

If you need to use that key to lookup `Node1` elements by `@ParentName` in other areas without regard to what the `@IsInternal` value is, then you could filter the items returned from the key lookup:

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('ParentName',@ParentName)[@IsInternal='true']" >
    <SubItems>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </SubItems>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

You could also define a key that uses the value of both the `@ParentName` and the `@IsInternal` values as the key value:

```
<xsl:key name="ParentName" match="Node1" 
         use="concat(@ParentName,'-',@IsInternal)" />
```

and then retrieve them with the same key value:

```
key('ParentName',concat(@ParentName,'-',@IsInternal))
```